# I got an error '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'System.EventHandler' while executing the following code

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
case "Calendar":
    ctrl = new Calendar();
    ((Calendar)ctrl).ID = GetControlId(index, itemDetails);
    ((Calendar)ctrl).Attributes.Add("class", "chkClass" + parentIndex.ToString());

     if (itemDetails.AttachEvent == true)
     {
         ((Calendar)ctrl).SelectedDate += new EventHandler(Item_Selected);
         ((Calendar)ctrl).AutoPostBack = true;
     }
     break;
```

Error happens in this line:

```
((Calendar)ctrl).SelectedDate += new EventHandler(Item_Selected);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `SelectedDate` should be an event, but appears to be a `DateTime` property.

Comment: You have ctrl as Calendar type and always casting it? SelectedDate is not event and you trying to add event handler? Read c# for begginers book please.

Comment: Well .... how about: `'+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'System.EventHandler'`? What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: outsourcing quality at it's best

Comment: Given the [amount of questions asking about this error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cannot+be+applied+to+operands), perhaps it is worthwhile editing one of them into a main resource, simply explaining what the error means? From then on simply closing as duplicate would be possible.

Comment: Got worked when i changed SelectedDate in to SelectionChanged..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not register an event handler to a property. You can register handlers to events;

```
((Calendar)ctrl).SelectionChanged+= new EventHandler(Item_Selected);
```

Comment: Got worked when i changed SelectedDate in to SelectionChanged.

Answer (score 0):

SelectedDate is a property, you cannot assign an event handler to it, it holds the value of the Calendar's selected date.

As you are trying to handle an event, I believe you want to add your handler to `SelectionChanged`

I'm assuming it's ASP.NET (due to the AutoPostBack property), it will be a different event in WinForms

Comment: Got worked when i changed SelectedDate in to SelectionChanged. And removed auopostback

Answer (score 0):

[SelectedDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is a property wich is a System.DateTime that represents the selected date.
You should use [SelectionChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selectionchanged%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
((Calendar)ctrl).SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(Item_Selected);
```